# javascript fails to identify space character

Tags: javascript, string

i am getting a stack trace from a REST service which looks like:

```
 oracle.mds.core.MetadataNotFoundException: MDS-00013: no metadata found for metadata object "/WEB-INF/root_menu_tm.xml" [[MDS-00201: PDocument not found in MetadataStore : [store-type=DefaultMetadataStore app-name=ORA_CRM_UIAPP lookup-order=ServletContext,Classpath]     at oracle.mds.core.MetadataObject.getBaseMO(MetadataObject.java:1600)   at oracle.mds.core.MDSSession.getMetadataObject(MDSSession.java:1663)   at oracle.apps.fnd.applcore.patterns.uishell.model.ApplicationsMenuModel.getMetadatObject(ApplicationsMenuModel.java:891)   at oracle.apps.fnd.applcore.patterns.uishell.model.ApplicationsMenuModel._createModel(ApplicationsMenuModel.java:492)   at oracle.apps.fnd.applcore.patterns.uishell.model.ApplicationsMenuModel.setSource(ApplicationsMenuModel.java:177)  at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)  at
```

I am trying to format it in my javascript before displaying on UI. The idea is simple: just replace all the

```
<space>at
```

with

`<br/>at`

I have tried various options like:

```
var trace = (d.MsgDetails).replace(new RegExp('\sat','g'),'</p><p>at');
```

or

```
var trace = (d.MsgDetails).replace(new RegExp(' at','g'),'</p><p>at');
```

or

```
 var trace = (d.MsgDetails).replace(/at/g),'</p><p>at');
```

or

```
 var trace = (d.MsgDetails).replace(/ at/g),'</p><p>at');
```

and nothing works. I am hoping the space which it looks is really a space. removing the space works fine but that is not what i want as it will break good words too.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The character before “at” is a tab, so:

```
var trace = d.MsgDetails.replace(/\tat/g, '</p><p>at');
```

(Your first regular expression with `\s` would have worked if you had escaped `\` in the string literal for an overall `\\s`; a string literal `'\s'` is equivalent to `'s'`. Don’t use the `RegExp` constructor to create static regular expressions.)

If there are in fact some newlines in there, a neater solution might be:

```
var traceLines = d.MsgDetails.split('\n');
var trace = document.createDocumentFragment();

traceLines.forEach(function (line) {
    trace.appendChild(document.createElement('p')).textContent = line;
});
```

Comment: Doesn't `\s` match tabs? The OP's first attempt had `/\sat/`.

Comment: @nnnnnn: Explanation added